# Deleting from 3 MySQL tables using a join without locking

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I'm currently in the situation where I need to delete rows from three different MySQL tables, which are linked by a common column. For simplicity, tables A, B and C have a common column, common_column. There is a time field available in table A, time_column, and I need to delete the rows from all three tables where the time_column is before a certain date.

Example:
**Table A:**

| common_column | time-column |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 15-04-2020 |
| 124 | 16-04-2020 |
| 125 | 17-04-2020 |

**Table B**

| common_column | random_column |
| --- | --- |
| 122 | 1 |
| 123 | 1 |
| 124 | 1 |

**Table C**

| common_column | random_column |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 |
| 126 | 1 |
| 127 | 1 |

And I want to delete all rows prior to 17-04-2020.

The resulting tables should look as follows:
**Table A:**

| common_column | time-column |
| --- | --- |
| 125 | 17-04-2020 |

**Table B**

| common_column | random_column |
| --- | --- |
| 122 | 1 |

**Table C**

| common_column | random_column |
| --- | --- |
| 126 | 1 |
| 127 | 1 |

I have tried to use a join to do this, but since I have millions of rows in each table it ends up locking. Does anyone know another way of doing this? I have seen some examples using LIMIT but I don't know how to do that exactly. Thanks

As mentioned in the details, I have attempted using a join to delete the rows but I am experiencing locking issues.

Comment: Is the time column a date type?  Or is it really the dd-mm-yyyy string you show?

Comment: How many rows do you expect it to delete in total?

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE A, B, C
FROM A
JOIN B ON A.common_column = B.common_column
JOIN C ON A.common_column = C.common_column
WHERE A.time_column < '17-04-2020'
LIMIT 1000;
```

I think this is what you are trying to do. You just need to put Limit  at the end. If it still locks, reduce the limit number, but I doubt that will happen. If not, experiment with increasing it. You will need to run this a few times, the higher the limit number, the less times you need to run it.

Comment: I thought this would still cause locking. From some brief researching I have seen some articles stating that you should rather limit the number of rows from one of the tables before joining with the others. In this case, limit the number of rows from Table A to 1000 and join using just those rows.

Comment: Pretty sure only the single table delete supports limit & order by